# How to modify software architecture in order to resolve circular import?

Tags: python, python-2.7, importerror

I am currently writing some Python 2.7 code for population model simulations, and I have come across a problem with circular imports.

The model has the following structure:

`Island` class (in `landscape.py`)

- Collection of landscape cells with coordinates

`Cell` class (in `landscape.py`)

- Superclass for all landscape cells (`Jungle`, `Savannah`, `Mountain`, etc.). The cell class has a dictionary with the different animals in this cell.
- The `animal` dictionary is structured like this:

  ```
  animals = {AnimalType1: [animal1_inst_1, animal_2_inst_2],
             AnimalType2: [animal2_inst_1, animal_2_inst_2]}
  ```
- The initial `animal` dictionary for each cell is set at runtime.

`Animal` class (in `animals.py`)

- Superclass for all animal types (currently only `Herbivore` and `Carnivore`).
- All animals classes have a class-variable, `allowed_cells`, which is a list of all cell types this animal can reside in, e.g.

  ```
  allowed_cells = [landscape.Jungle, landscape.Savannah]
  ```

My problem is this - animals.py is imported in landscape.py to check if all keys in the animal dictionary are `Animal` subclasses and if all instances in the corresponding list are instances of that animal class. In `animals.py`, `landscape.py` is imported so that the `allowed_cells` list can be with actual cell classes, in addition to many tests elsewhere.

When I try to run the code, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yngve_000/Documents/INF200/inf200_dag_yngve/PA04/biosim/simulation.py", line 10, in <module>
    import landscape as landscape
  File "C:\Users\yngve_000\Documents\INF200\inf200_dag_yngve\PA04\biosim\landscape.py", line 12, in <module>
    import animals
  File "C:\Users\yngve_000\Documents\INF200\inf200_dag_yngve\PA04\biosim\animals.py", line 18, in <module>
    class Animal(object):
  File "C:\Users\yngve_000\Documents\INF200\inf200_dag_yngve\PA04\biosim\animals.py", line 70, in Animal
    allowed_cell_types = [landscape.Jungle, landscape.Desert,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Jungle'
```

I understand why this error arises, but not how to remove it in an elegant way. It would be possible to create an is_animal function for the Animal class and use some workaround with try/except, but that seems very bodgey to say the least.

What is the best workaround for this?

Comment: You say that *The initial animal dictionary for each cell is set at runtime*. Simply move that code to a place where both modules have been imported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems natural that `animals` imports `landscape` in order to define where an animal can live. On the other hand I don't see why you need `Animal`s in `landscape`. A cell can (possibly) exist without any `Animal` on it, but each `Animal` must live in a cell. So you should try to remove the animal stuff from `landscape` and this module should only contain the landscape classes. The instantiation should happen in a different module and the cells should be populated with animals upon instantiation. So make the animal list an argument to `__init__`.

Note that you can perform checks of the form `is_animal` through subclass checks. I.e. if `Dog` inherits from `Animal` then `issubclass(Dog, Animal)` evaluates to `True`. You can also use [abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) to [register](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register) other classes as subclasses.

Comment: The reason I'm importing Animals to landscape is there to prevent users from adding non-animal class to a cell with the cell.add_animal() function. To prevent this from happening we're using 
`if not isinstance(new_animal, animals.Animal): raise ValueError("...")`.

Would you reccomend removing this altogether then?

Comment: You can pass the `animals.Animal` 'reference class' to the landscape at __init__ in the master file as a_guest suggests. I.e. master: `savannah = Landscape.Cell(animals.Animal)` and landscape: `if not isinstance(new_animal, self.referenceAnimal): raise...`

Comment: I agree with @dodell here. You should configure the cell through its `__init__`. Imagine you want to create a cell which only accepts `Plant` s (or `Vehicle`s, or whatever else). If you prefer a static design (i.e. cells that are statically configured for `Animal`s) then you could create a separate module `animal_landscape` (for example) and import both `landscape` and `animal` there in order to define a `AnimalOnlyCell` that can use `animal.Animal` for its `isinstance` checks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import `Animal` inside `landscape.py` not at the beginning of the file, but locally, *inside a function* which checks keys classes.

Actually, it's common approach — to use local imports when you face circular imports. But be careful — circular imports often are signal that your code has troubles with coupling.

Comment: I'm afraid that won't be possible, as we are strictly bound by the PEP-8 style guide.

Comment: _But be careful — circular imports often are signal that your code has troubles with coupling._ I definitely agree with that. Instead of inventing some artificial twists one should review the code and restructure it appropriately. Circular imports are a strong hint for an inadequate software design. And while the codebase grows things might get even worse. It's better to fix such problems in a sophisticated way the moment you realize them (rather than later when you realize that you eventually hit a dead end).
@YngveMoe Following PEP8 there's nothing wrong with local imports.

Comment: @a_guest sometimes there is no reasonable way to avoid local imports (as workarounds for circular imports).

Comment: @YngveMoe there are no restrictions about local imports in PEP-0008: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports